# Setting Value Firebase - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have some problems with Swift 3 and Firebase. 
My error is `Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT.`
My error is this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at book_key. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'
```

My code is this:

```
var book_key, book_title, book_authors, book_publisher, number_pages, book_price, book_urlPicture1, book_urlPicture2, book_condition: String!

 var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Books").child("User's books")
        book_key = ref.childByAutoId().key


let valuesBook: NSDictionary = ["book_key": book_key, "book_title": book_title, "book_author": book_authors, "book_price": book_price, "book_publisher": book_publisher, "page_count": number_pages, "book_description": "", "book_urlImage": book_urlPicture1, "book_urlImage2": book_urlPicture2, "book_condition": book_condition]

 ref.child(book_key).setValue(valuesBook)
```

If I print my valuesBook in my app the result is absolutely correct. Like this:

```
{
"book_author" = Gg;
"book_condition" = "Very Good";
"book_description" = "";
"book_key" = "-KS0DIr6cQkI0oxsgwPU";
"book_price" = 3;
"book_publisher" = Jj;
"book_title" = Gg;
"book_urlImage" = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/book_key%2F-KS0DIr6cQkI0oxsgwPUfirstImage.jpg?alt=media&token=231324bd-5b3a-4e3e-935f-2f1177da404a";
"book_urlImage2" = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginsample-myapp.appspot.com/o/book_key%2F-KS0DIr6cQkI0oxsgwPUsecondImage.jpg?alt=media&token=cc207ba4-46a6-4552-a65c-13ef7c4df5ee";
"page_count" = 5;

}
```

**The result is saved in my Database but the app crashes.**
I didn't have any errors before swift 3. Any Ideas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to happen in swift 3 when you have Optionals in your dictionary, Try declaring your variables as `String` with an initial value of an empty string instead of `String!`, like this

```
var book_key = "", book_title = "", book_authors = "", book_publisher = "", number_pages = "", book_price = "", book_urlPicture1 = "", book_urlPicture2 = "", book_condition = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I have found the solution. 
Now I'm using this:

```
let valuesBook = ["book_key": book_key, "book_title": book_title, "book_author": book_authors, "book_price": book_price, "book_publisher": book_publisher, "page_count": number_pages, "book_description": "", "book_urlImage": book_urlPicture1, "book_urlImage2": book_urlPicture2, "book_condition": book_condition] as [String: Any]
```

instead of this:

```
let valuesBook: NSDictionary = ["book_key": book_key, "book_title": book_title, "book_author": book_authors, "book_price": book_price, "book_publisher": book_publisher, "page_count": number_pages, "book_description": "", "book_urlImage": book_urlPicture1, "book_urlImage2": book_urlPicture2, "book_condition": book_condition]
```

Comment: Yes this also works but be careful if any of those variables are nil your program will crash at this line

Comment: It's best to avoid implicitly unwrapped optional in most cases.